# remove duplicate word from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with information like below stored in one column

```
>>> Results.Category[:5]
0    issue delivery wrong master account
1      data wrong master account batch
2    order delivery wrong data account
3    issue delivery wrong master account
4    delivery wrong master account batch
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Now I want to keep unique word in Category column
For Example :
In first row word "wrong" is present I want to remove it from all rest of the rows and keep word "wrong" in first row only
In second row word "data" is available then I want to remove it from all rest of the rows and keep word "data" in second row only

I found that if duplicates are available in row we can remove using below , but I need to remove duplicate words from columns, Can anyone please help me here.

```
AFResults['FinalCategoryN'] = AFResults['FinalCategory'].apply(lambda x: remove_dup(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want something like,

```
out = []
seen = set()
for c in df['Category']:
    words = c.split()
    out.append(' '.join([w for w in words if w not in seen]))
    seen.update(words)

df['FinalCategoryN'] = out
df

                              Category                       FinalCategoryN
0  issue delivery wrong master account  issue delivery wrong master account
1      data wrong master account batch                           data batch
2    order delivery wrong data account                                order
3  issue delivery wrong master account                                     
4  delivery wrong master account batch
```

---

If you don't care about the ordering, you can use set logic:

```
u = df['Category'].apply(str.split)
v = split.shift().map(lambda x: [] if x != x else x).cumsum().map(set)
(u.map(set) - v).str.join(' ')

0    account delivery issue master wrong
1                             batch data
2                                  order
3                                       
4                                       
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is perfect I was looking for this result, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In you case you need `split` it first then remove duplicate by `drop_duplicates`

```
df.c.str.split(expand=True).stack().drop_duplicates().\
     groupby(level=0).apply(','.join).reindex(df.index)
Out[206]: 
0    issue,delivery,wrong,master,account
1                             data,batch
2                                  order
3                                    NaN
4                                    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

What you what cannot be vectorized, so let us just forget about pandas and use a Python `set`:

```
total = set()
result = []
for line in AFResults['FinalCategory']:
    line = set(line.split()).difference(total)
    total = total.union(line)
    result.append(' '.join(line))
```

You get that list: `['wrong issue master delivery account', 'batch data', 'order', '', '']`

You can use it to populate a dataframe column:

```
AFResults['FinalCategoryN'] = result
```

Comment: It worked, I just added "line = set(line.split()).difference(total)" in your code to capture word earlier it was capturing letter for capturing duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` with `sorted` and `set` and `str.join` and `list.index`:

```
AFResults['FinalCategoryN'] = AFResults['FinalCategory'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(set(x.split()), key=x.index)))
```