# How to use python to get unique values from a column?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a dataframe looks like this.

This is an order form.

```
ORDER NUMBER    PROMOTION CODE                        ORDER AMOUNT      
abc1            128040;128040;128040;128040           3160
abc2            128040;127497;128040;128040;134497    1381        
abc3            128406;128040;128040                  345
abc4            NaN                                   698
```

I want to get unique PROMOTION CODE for each order,and the final dataframe would looks like this:

```
ORDER NUMBER    PROMOTION CODE                        ORDER AMOUNT      
abc1            128040                                3160
abc2            128040;127497;134497                  1381        
abc3            128406;128040                         345
abc4            NaN                                   698
```

I dont know how to drop these duplicate promotion code by python

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what are you using? what you mean with dataframe? pandas? please post the code you are using, otherwise the best we can tell you is to use `set()`

Comment: Hey look at this stackoverflow question:
[remove duplicate words in pandas colomn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853948/remove-duplicate-word-from-pandas-column)

Answer (score 1):

For a regex option, we could try using `str.replace` here:

```py
df["PROMOTION CODE"] = df["PROMOTION CODE"].str.replace(r';?(\d+)\b(?=.*;\1)', '').str.lstrip(';')
```

Comment: But it returns a warning:FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.

Could you please elaborate on the reason of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Using **split** follow with **pd.unique** and **join**

```
df['PROMOTION CODE'] = df['PROMOTION CODE'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(pd.unique(x.split(';'))))
```